# Enum for .mlmodels?

Tags: swift, xcode, coreml, apple-vision, createml

So I am currently working on a project that includes image recognition with CreateML, CoreML, and Vision. I am still trying datasets and improving the models with CreateML, but if I change from a model to another, I have to manually change a variable `let model = example()` that Xcode creates for me when I import the `.mlmodel` file into the project. So I wanted to do a tableView with the name of those models files so if I tap on one of them, it takes me to the "RecognitionVC", passing the name as a variable so I can instantiate the class with an enum from a `rawValue(string)` and then access its "model variable" which I cannot achieve.

This is what the enum would look like:

```
enum MLModels: String {
    case example
    case letters
    case ab
    case numbers
    case asl
}
```

And this is what I would like to achieve:

```
   func getModel() -> AnyClass {
        switch self {
        case .example:
            return example()
...
        }
    }

    var model: MLModel {
        switch self {
        case .example:
            return example()
...
        }
    }
```

I am new to these machine learning built in frameworks, if someone could let me know what am I doing wrong or how can I achieve this I would be very grateful.I am including some screenshots. And in case you want to test anything I am including the link to apple's public models:

[link](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/models/)

[image: folder]
[image: example1]
[image: example2]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems to me that you are facing a design pattern issue more than a CoreML one, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `example()` it creates an instance of a wrapper class. This is not an `MLModel`. However, it does have the `MLModel` as a property, so you could write `return example().model` to do what you want.

Comment: is this working for you ?? doesn't it give errors asking about to have an MLFeatureprovider or something ??